# reversing a String in java

Tags: java

Code to revers a string in java:
NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra copy of the array is not.

Now  i have implemented a algo as follows:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str) {
  if (str == null) return;
  int len = str.length;
  if (len < 2) return;

  int tail = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
   int j;
     for (j = 0; j < tail; ++j) {
       if (str[i] == str[j]) break;
     }
     if (j == tail) {
       str[tail] = str[i];
       ++tail;
     }
   }
   str[tail] = something //something to mark end of char array eg '\0' as we have in C
 }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You want to implement String reverse b'coz there a function called **String.reverse();**

Comment: actually its StringBuilder.reverse();

Comment: Is this the correct code snippet? You want to reverse string but have a method called removeDuplicates() ?

Comment: Its a interview question:REversing a string without using extra space

Comment: @DaveHowes:Was tring that function before revresing, dont mind the function name

Comment: you cannot reverse the string without saving an extra string, because in java string is immutable.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it such (pseudocode):

```
// s is array of char that holds the string
i=0
j=s.length - 1
while (i < j) 
    swap characters at positions i and j
    i++
    j--
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Apache Commons StringUtils class:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

It has a great reverse function:

```
static String reverse(String str);
```

Comment: Its a interview question:REversing a string without using extra space

Answer (score 1):

you cannot reverse a String in java without extra space, because String is immutable in java.

seems like a trick question...

 if you want to revers char[] it should be something like:

```
    char[] str = "abcdefg".toCharArray();
    int len = str.length;
    int n = len / 2;
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len-1-i];
        str[len-1-i] = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, reversing a String object is not possible, as string objects in Java are immutable.

You could circumvent this by using reflection to access the underlying array (see below), but this is not advisable.

If we take a question as working on a `char[]` (or any other array) instead, it gets easy:

```
/**
 * reverses an array by swapping its elements.
 */
public static void reverse(char[] array) {
    reverse(array, 0, array.length);
}

/**
 * reverses a section of an array by swapping its elements.
 * @param start the start of the section, inclusive
 * @param end the end of the section, exclusive
 */
public static void reverse(char[] array, int start, int end) {
    for(int i = start, j = end-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        swap(array, i, j);
    }
}

/**
 * swaps two array elements.
 */
private static void swap(char[] array, int i, int j) {
    char help = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = help;
}
```

Having this, we can now also cheat to reverse an existing string:

```
public static void reverse(String s) {
    Class<String> sClass = String.class;
    char[] array = (char[])sClass.getDeclaredField("value").get(s);
    int start = sClass.getDeclaredField("offset").getInt(s);
    int len = sClass.getDeclaredField("count").getInt(s);
    reverse(array, start, start+len);
}
```

As said, this is not advisable since the whole VM and standard library is based on the fact that Strings are immutable. Also, the field names here are taken from the 1.6.0_13 Sun implementation, other VMs may have other names for these fields, or store strings in another way altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this?

```
string input = "ABCD";
string result = "";
for (int i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  result = result + input[i];
}
```

Comment: I think that's going to produce a few extra copies of the array (in typical implementations). Use also want `charAt` and a couple more caps and `()`.

Comment: -1 because: 1. it is not java, or it won't compile at least: (need to use String and not string, also need to use charAt() and not []) 2. you create an extra copies (extra n space if it supposed to be  c++) and in java, it will actually require (n^2)/2 more space....